How to disable verbose logging in React Native Expo?
React Native: 0.72.5
Expo: 49.0.10
Using the iOS Simulator
I'm seeing hundreds of logs, without prompting, and for every little UI button I press, or scroll a listview. Its highly annoying because the logs I want to see are impossible to find.
For example, there are tons like this

[MediaToolbox] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> itemfig_setCurrentTimeWithRangeAndIDGuts: [0x162ef3e00] I/YGB.02 called, time = 0.000, flags =
[MediaToolbox] <<<< Boss >>>> FigPlaybackBossSetTimeWithRange: (0x165c7c980) playState set to Paused

How do I disable this?

I am suggesting You to try this, solution, based on Your question.

@SaurabhDVyas thank you, I that but it doesn't work. The issue is not in Xcode.

You can try this in Xcode to reduce the verbosity of logs:

Open your project in Xcode.
Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme.
Select the "Run" action on the left.
Go to the "Arguments" tab.
Add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with the value disable in the "Environment Variables" section.

Alternatively, you can try something like this in your entry file index.js:


if (__DEV__) {
  const nativeLog = console.log;
  console.log = (...args) => {
    const logMessage = args[0];
    if (typeof logMessage === 'string' && (logMessage.includes('[MediaToolbox]') || logMessage.includes('[CFNetwork]') ||       logMessage.includes('[Security]'))) {
      return;
    }
    nativeLog(...args);
  };
}




Thanks, the first answer I'd already tried. The alternative answer works, but for just MediaToolbox logs, not others, such as [CFNetwork] or [Security]. Do you have any way to fix those as well?
Also, if you know why this is happening, I'd greatly appreciate it

I have added an update for the other ones. As for why it's happening, it depends on the context of your application `[MediaToolbox] logs may be related to media processing, [CFNetwork] logs may be related to network communication, and [Security] logs may be related to security-related activities. @MendyK

Thank you, but there are lots more besides CFNetwork and Security. How do I disable all of them?

If the issue is not in the XCode, you can try Modify Info.plist: You need to edit the Info.plist file located in your project directory under ios/YourProjectName/. Add the following lines within the dict tag:
<key>NSLogShowAssertionMessages</key>
<false/>


An Expo app hasn't got any access to the iOS or Android folder, So the developer can't modify any native files.

Native Swift/OC developers view logs related to their apps in the Xcode console; they rarely view the logs in macOS Console App. And in most cases, what they see inside Xcode's Console only relates to their apps. You can also open up the Xcode project to view it in RN development, RN generates a xxx.xcworkspace for you in the ios directory.


But for React Native developers, we can also launch our app directory in the terminal. You must be viewing the logs in the Console.app. But without proper filtering, your console app will be flooded with logs from other system processes. Most logs of these processes are not related to your app.
For example, the MediaToolbox/FigFilePlayer log messages you pasted are just from Apple's backend frameworks for media playback; your operation in Apple Music even triggers these logs.
I also have the same logs on my mac's Console:


So, you can filter the logs from your app by entering your app's executable's name(assuming fooBar as the process name) as the filter:

Apple offers a well-documented page here; please take a look.

Thank you. But why can't I use the regular terminal to view logs? I've always been able to until recently

Because of the noises in the terminal ?

I understand, but there were never noises before now.

OK, i did not know you were view these in terminal, these log noises sometimes even occur in Xcode, filtering them in code may not be a wise choice.
